# how to select some fields from tables in CakePHP

Tags: sql, cakephp

I tried to make query in cakephp with joins, but i want to get more fileds,

**Here the query sql :**

```
SELECT
   sd.debut,
   sd.fin,
   fr.id,
   f.id as formtaion_id,
   s.id as seance_id,
   fr.nom as formateur,
   f.nom as formation,
   r.title,
   f.module,
   sd.module as partie ,
   f.couleur 
FROM seances s 
   INNER JOIN formations f on s.formation_id = f.id
   INNER JOIN seances_dates sd on s.id = sd.seance_id
   INNER JOIN salles sa on sa.id = s.salle_id
   INNER JOIN regions r on r.id = sa.region_id
   INNER JOIN presence_formateurs pf ON pf.seance_id = s.id  
   INNER JOIN formateurs fr ON fr.id = pf.formateur_id
   WHERE fr.archived = 0
      AND fr.deleted is null
      AND (
            (sd.debut between '".$from."' and '".$to."')
            OR
            (sd.fin between '".$from."' and '".$to."')
          )
GROUP BY sd.id
ORDER BY sd.debut
```

please help me to make that query in cakephp :

> ClassRegistry::init('seance')->find('all'....

Comment: Did you created any Model?

Comment: no will make plugin in cakephp and just i will call some model like this:              require(ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.'models'.DS.'formateur.php');

Answer (score 1):

You should read very carefully
1. [How to Retrieve data in CakePHP](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#namespace-Cake%5CORM) and
2. [How to make Relation with different table](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together)